# What is the expected encoding for QWebView::setHtml?

Tags: qt, unicode, encoding, utf-8, qwebview

I found a strange effect that I do not understand: I have a HTML file encoded in UTF-8. It also has a meta element with `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`.

If I load the HTML file in QWebView, it is displayed correctly.

If I load the HTML file in a QByteArray (still looks like valid UTF-8), convert it into a QString (still looks like valid UTF-8), and set this via setHTML on the QWebView, it is displayed incorrectly (as if interpreted as ASCII).

If I take the same QByteArray, and set it via setContent on the QWebView, passing "text/html; charset=UTF-8" as mime type, it is displayed correctly again.

What is the expected encoding for QWebView::setHtml? The documentation only mentions that external CSS and script files are interpreted as UTF-8. This is using Qt 4.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no expected encoding because the text should already have been decoded to 16-bit unicode when you created the `QString`.  It's up to you to do that correctly, but if you used the `QString(const QByteArray&)` constructor then Qt will by default treat the contents as ASCII.

If you want to treat the content as UTF-8 then you can use `QString::fromUtf8`.  If you need to do something more sophisticated you can use `QTextCodec` to read many different encodings.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I got confused over the utf-8 vs. unicode encoding in the QString. I actually tried QTextCodec to see if it made a difference but used it incorrectly. Everything clearer the next day ;)

Comment: I think the source of confusion was that the encoding is taken from meta tag when loading a file but assumed to be 16-bit unicode when setting from QString, so essentially charset=... is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I iterate many cases, but true was in that:

QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF8"));

because QtWebKit uses a converting to std::string inside self.

Answer (score 0):

I used setContent(bytearray, "text/html; charset=utf-8") and it worked.  The "utf-8" should be in lowercase.